# JS - Knex, Pass function to Transaction

Tags: javascript, promise, knex.js

I created a node.js application that uses the knex library to make database operations. The database is Microsoft SQL Server. I created a script called db.js that returns the knex object, and i have a controller.js script that makes the actually needed database operations. I have all the operations wrapped inside a translation statement, which brings me to my question. What i would like to do, is pass in a parameter that tells the transaction to rollback or commit. However, whenever i try to pass this function in, it just fails. Does anyone know if this feature achievable ? I was able to do this feature with the catch function.

I don't think its db specific, so anyone can download knex, hook it up a db and give it a shot with the code below.

example.js

```
/**
 * @param {userID} Int 
 * @param {rollback} Boolean 
 */
const getUsers = (userID, rollback) => {
    // Using tran as a transaction object:
    return db('master').transaction((tran) => {
        db('master')
        .select()
        .from('users')
        .where({ 'user_id': userID })
        .transacting(tran)
        .then(tran.rollback) // Works
        // .then(transact(tran, rollback)) throws error 
        .catch((error) => {
            logError(error, tran); // Works 
        });
        // .catch(tran.rollback);
    });
};
const logError = (error, transaction) => {
    transaction.rollback; 
    console.log('transaction error: ',error);
    console.log('transaction log: ',transaction);
};
const transact = (transaction, rollback) => {
    try {
        if (rollback) return transaction.rollback; 
        else return transaction.commit;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error); 
    }
}; 
const user = await getUsers(1, true); // error is thrown
assert.strictEqual(user.constructor === Array, true);
assert.strictEqual(user.length == 0, true);
```

Error Message

```
Error: the array [   {
    "user_id": 1
    "user_name": "JonnyBoy"
    "zip": 1200
    "email": "jjboy@test.com"
  } ] was thrown, throw an Error :)
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @Mark_M, error added.

Answer (score 1):

`then` takes a function as its first parameter. If the Promise resolves, the function that's passed to `then` is called with the value the Promise resolved to. The `rollback` property on the transaction object is a function so you can write:

```
someQuery().then(trans.rollback)
```

and `rollback` will be called when `someQuery` resolves. You could also write:

```
someQuery.then(result => trans.rollback(result))
```

These statements are equivalent.

That said, minimally, there's two changes that you need to make. One, fix how you're calling `transact`. For example:

```
.then(() => transact(tran, rollback))
```

And change how `transact` calls `rollback`:

```
const transact = (trx, rollback) => {
  const action = rollback ? trx.rollback : trx.commit
  return action()
}
```

Also bear in mind that `rollback` itself will return a rejected Promise with a generic error. You can pass a custom error to `rollback` and it will reject with that error instead.